# Android: Using ImageView onclick to change image back and forth

Tags: android

Code that is not working

```
public void fade(View v){
    ImageView pic1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic1);
    ImageView pic2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic2);
    pic1.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
    pic2.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);

}
```

Comment: add more details on what you wanna do?

Comment: I used the "Onclick" properties from the ImageView to change the pic1 into pic2. It went well. The code hide the pic1 and show pic2. Now, I want to tap the pic2 to hide it and show the pic1 or back and forth...

Comment: You wanna change between 2 pictures, and when tapping on the `ImageView`, it will change alternatively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure what you are asking for, but if you want to change the image back and forth onClick, you could try modifying the code I wrote below.

```
// set a boolean value
private boolean firstImageShown = true;


public void clickFunction(View view) {


    ImageView firstImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.firstImage);

    if ((firstImage != null) && (firstImageShown)) {
        firstImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.sample_image2);
        firstImageShown = false;
    } else {
        if (firstImage != null) firstImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.sample_image1);
        firstImageShown = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: I have to click it twice the first time to change it. What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I wrote this answer quite a while back... It's hard to tell without your code, but are you setting the default image in the layout?

Answer (score 1):

```
//Suppose you have two images rose_1 and rose_2 and you want to switch back
//and forth between these on a button press.

//Set a static variable 
private static int switcherPressedCount = 2;


//Map the onClick attribute of the button to a function say "switcherPressed".
//"imageView1" is the id attribute of the image which first gets loaded in the 
//app, in this example, it is the attribute of rose_1.
public void switcherPressed(View view){
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        if(switcherPressedCount%2 == 0) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.rose_2);
            switcherPressedCount = 3; //to avoid reaching maximum int limit.
        }
        else {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.rose_1);
            switcherPressedCount = 2; //to avoid reaching maximum int limit.
        }
    }
```